# short cut entry in KeyEventTranslations.tr works on V 10.0.2 but does not work in V 10.1

Tags: keyboard

I added 2 useful key shortcuts to my V 10.0.2 `KeyEventTranslations.tr` to allow adding `[[` and `]]`  using `ctrl-[` and `ctrl-]`  (thanks to this post by  Szabolcs at [WRI community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/200624) some time ago) and these worked find and still work fine in V 10.0.2

Now I did the same thing in windows 10.1 but for some reason, they do not work. I get the error

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The file I edited is (as Admin)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.1\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\KeyEventTranslations.tr`

And the 2 lines added are

```
Item[KeyEvent["[", Modifiers -> {Control}], FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", After]}]],
Item[KeyEvent["]", Modifiers -> {Control}], FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "\[RightDoubleBracket]", After]}]],
```

Right at the start, here is screen shot of the file as it stands now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the above is exactly the same as on V 10.0.2

Now when I restart V 10.1 and hit `ctrl-[` or `ctrl-]`  I get the above error.

Has something changed in V10.1 to cause this? I am using windows 7, 64 bit

I rebooted the PC, restarted M few times. I also did rest (hold down the ctrl and SHIFT key while M was starting to rest it to factory setting), but still get same error.

Any idea what do I need to do to get these short cuts to work like with V 10.0.2?

Comment: Have you solved it? Now I have problem in V10.2, in Mac.